# fadeout jquery in specific div

Tags: jquery, html, fadeout

I want to fadeOut a specific div that was selected using class.

So my HTML looks like this

```
<div class="container" id="conversations">
 <button class="delete" id="1"></button>
</div>

<div class="container" id="conversations">
 <button class="delete" id="2"></button>
</div>

<div class="container" id="conversations">
 <button class="delete" id="3"></button>
</div>
```

So heres the case, if I selected delete button with ID that is equals to 3, how will I fadeout its current div element?

This is my jQuery as of now (not working)

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
          $(this).fadeOut();
    });
```

These are the functions that I tried

```
$('div.container').fadeOut(1000); // working but remove all divs
                $(this).fadeOut(); // not working
                jQuery(this).parent('div.container').fadeOut(1000); // not working
                $(this).parent("div.container").fadeOut(); // not working
                $(this).parent($('div.container')).fadeOut(); // not working
```

Update:

Solves this issue by re-initializing again its element

```
var _this = $(this);
```

I call the $(this).fadeOut() in the success callback of ajax where by callings $(this), you are pointing to the success function.

So by doing this inside the success callback func it is now working:

```
_this.parent('div.container').fadeOut();
```

Comment: your code is working fine you fade out the current selected button if you want to select parent element than try "$(this).parent("div.container").fadeOut();"

Comment: still not working :( tried all that stuff before going in stack. I am using jquery 3.4 maybe its the cause or what?

Comment: replace every "$" with "jQuery" it will work

Comment: so it will be jQuery(this).fadeOut()?

Comment: Yes , please try because sometime $ is not working and we can use jQuery instead of $

Comment: stil not working thou. :( @AnkushKumar

Comment: Please check your browser console is there any error

Comment: I also checked that. There's no error at all. I tried to use the id and of course it will only fadeOut the first div element.

Comment: The code you provided works fine.  The issue is here "*I call the $(this).fadeOut() in the success callback of ajax*" - which **was not mentioned originally** - the simple answer is that `this` depends on the context and it will be different inside the success callback.  In future, please ensure you include *all* the relevant information.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 0):

The above code should work, it is working for me. Add some content to the button in order to see the difference.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/uxmfnsb7/1/][1]
```

Comment: Did you see that message that said link only answers are not allowed?  Do you think they added that for fun?  Did you feel superior finding a way to "get around" that restriction?  Add your code to your answer, or, in this case, just add an comment with the updated fiddle with "it works for me".

Answer (score 0):

> Your code is working fine

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<div class="container" id="conversations">
 <button class="delete" id="1">Button 1</button>
</div>

<div class="container" id="conversations">
 <button class="delete" id="2"> Button 2</button>
</div>

<div class="container" id="conversations">
 <button class="delete" id="3">Button 3</button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a pure javascript hide parent element on click try this.

```
  var g = document.getElementsByClassName('delete');
  for (var i = 0, len = g.length; i < len; i++)
  {

        (function(index){
            g[i].onclick = function(){
                  g[index].parentElement.style.display = "none";
            }    
        })(i);

  }
```